# Contact Builder Data Sources SFDC Objects Syncing Stuck at 0

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

I'm having an issue with some of my objects, specifically Users, Contacts and Leads. I went Multi-org back in early May and apparently, this has been throwing error since then. SFMC support suggested I login as tracking user and try to refresh the objects, but that didn't work. I reset the password in SFDC to match the password in SFMC for my api tracking user and also changed api user in SFDC to make sure it was up to date. All of this seems correct and SOME objects are syncing just fine, just not the ones mentioned above.

Has anyone experienced this before? My Lead, User and Contact objects are stuck at zero or they pause while trying to sync. Every time I force a refresh this happens. How can I delete the object entirely so that I can try with a fresh one?

Any other thoughts?

Comment: You have to clear the token on the Salesforce side , reconnect the account and re synchronise the objects

Comment: @Data_Kid you've had this problem before? I cleared tokens recently and reconnected from the SF side only. It fixed an error seeing business units, but did nothing to fix this. I'll give it a try though.

Comment: That did not work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few methods to try to get this resolved, one of the main things is to continue working with support as you may need their assistance.

The options I know of:

- Clearing Oauth Tokens on Salesforce Side
- Removing connection in MC, wait 15 minutes, re-connect on MC (and sometimes re-log inside Core)
- Issue on the backend, requiring support to fix something in the schema. This ***rarely*** happens, but believe i experienced this a year back.

Comment: I tried the first one and the second (but didn't wait 15). Fortunately, support FINALLY got around to fixing this issue.

Comment: Cool Garek007! Did they identify the issue?

Comment: I am no longer with the company, but what they told me was that salesforce said it was in fact some kind of bug that happened when they went multi-org. Something went haywire, so there was nothing that could have been done on the client end.